# How to access elements of a dictionary in python where the keys are bytes instead of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Sorry if it's too much of a noob question.

I have a dictionary where the keys are bytes (like `b'access_token'` ) instead of strings.

```
{
 b'access_token': [b'b64ssscba8c5359bac7e88cf5894bc7922xxx'], 
 b'token_type': [b'bearer']
}
```

usually I access the elements of a dictionary by `data_dict.get('key')`, but in this case I was getting `NoneType` instead of the actual value.

How do I access them or is there a way to convert this bytes keyed dict to string keyed dict?

**EDIT:** I actually get this dict from parsing a query string like this `access_token=absdhasd&scope=abc` by `urllib.parse.parse_qs(string)`

Comment: I get the value for instance: `print(data_dict.get(b'access_token'))` produces [b'b64ssscba8c5359bac7e88cf5894bc7922xxx'], where data_dict is the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `str.encode()` and `bytes.decode()` to swap between the two (optionally, providing an argument that specifies the encoding. `'UTF-8'` is the default). As a 
result, you can take your dict:

```
my_dict = {
 b'access_token': [b'b64ssscba8c5359bac7e88cf5894bc7922xxx'], 
 b'token_type': [b'bearer']
}
```

and just do a comprehension to swap all the keys:

```
new_dict = {k.decode(): v for k,v in my_dict.items()}
# {
#   'access_token': [b'b64ssscba8c5359bac7e88cf5894bc7922xxx'], 
#   'token_type': [b'bearer']
# }
```

---

Similarly, you can just use `.encode()` when accessing the dict in order to get a bytes object from your string:

```
my_key = 'access_token'
my_value = my_dict[my_key.encode()]
# [b'b64ssscba8c5359bac7e88cf5894bc7922xxx']
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work. I needed to prefix it with `b''`

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, you are making some silly mistake.
It is working fine in my tests.
Perhaps you forgot to add the prefix `b` when trying to index the dictionary

```
d={
 b'key1': [b'val1'], 
 b'key2': [b'val2']
}

d[b'key1']     # --> returns [b'val1']
d.get(b'key2') # --> returns [b'val2']
```

Comment: Thank you. It did work. I needed to prefix it with `b''` which obviously was missing from my code. What I was thinking is `b' `is some kind of special object so needed to omit it

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could be something you're looking for?

```
dict = {
    b'access_token': [b'b64ssscba8c5359bac7e88cf5894bc7922xxx'], 
    b'token_type': [b'bearer']
}
print(dict.get( b'access_token'))
```